# Save Clean CSV file from Excel using Applescript

Tags: excel, applescript

I have a process that requires downloading an Excel Spreadsheet from the Web, opening it using Excel Mac 2008, saving it as a csv file, and then parsing it using php. The manual process works fine and saves a clean CSV file. I am trying to automate this part using Applescript, and it sort of works, however, the CSV file generated contains a bunch of weird characters.

Here is the Applescript I am working on:

```
tell application id "com.microsoft.Excel" to open "~/Documents/input.xls"
tell application id "com.microsoft.Excel" to tell active sheet to save in ("output.csv") as "CSV file format"
```

I have tried various CSV options (Mac, Windows, MSDos) and they do not produce substantially different results.

Comment: Is there any way you can take that Excel step out of the process and just generate the CSV with whatever is generating the Excel file? It seems to me you could save a lot of potential problems because you'll probably be rewriting this once Excel gets updated.

Comment: Phillip: Unfortunately no. The Excel file is output from a website that is not very friendly, output options are html, pdf, and Excel. Of the three, Excel is the easiest to parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
set theDoc to (path to desktop as text) & "test.xlsx"
set outPath to (path to desktop as text) & "test.csv"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open file theDoc
    tell workbook 1
        tell sheet 1
            save in outPath as CSV file format
        end tell
        close without saving
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: regulus6633 thanks - looks like the major difference, other than the tell blocks, was that you did not have quotes around CSV file format in your save as command. I tried yours and it worked perfectly, then I tried mine removing the quotes, which also worked perfectly.